# Process 404 page when there is no parameter in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Dynamic routing is in use.

If there is no device data in vuex, I want to go to 404 page.

How should I implement it?

router/index.js

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Main',
    component: Main
  },
  {
    path: '/:device',
    name: 'Detail',
    component: Detail,
  },
  {
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound
  },

]
```

When the device-detail page is implemented as follows, it does not move to the 404 page.

```
    const deviceName = route.params.device
    const storedDeviceList = computed(() => store.state.stationName)

    if (!storedDeviceList.value.includes(deviceName)) {
      router.push({
        name: 'NotFound'
      })
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide how you handle this in the store?

Comment: Vuex-store has a stationName containing a list of devices.

`store/index.js` =>

  state: {
    stationName: [
      'sample', 
    ],
}

Comment: So, if stationName does not have a parameter (router-parameter), I tried to move to the NotFound page.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `deviceName` and `storedDeviceList`? Because I don´t see, why this shouldn´t work.

Comment: Sorry for checking late.
I posted a code example on github. (https://github.com/airwalk741/router-test)
There is only test_device in state.
If you go to a URL other than test_device, you will get an error. (For example http://localhost:8081/test123 This place throws an error.)

Comment: Inside about.vue is the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is, that you declare `router` two times in your project, according to your github repo. You declared your routes in your `router/index.js` and imported it into your `main.js`. So importing it again in `About.vue` from `vue-router` instead of `router.js` causes, that this instance has no routes. The second problem is the same with your store, as you import `store/index.js` to your `main.js` but import a new instance from `vuex` to your `About.vue`.

If you would use the composition API, you could call the already in `main.js` imported modules with `this`, like:

```
this.$router.push({
   name: 'NotFound'
})
```

You also would get your states from your store like this:

```
this.$store.state.stationName
```

So, in composition API, use something like this in your `About.vue`:

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    checkDevice() {
      if (!this.$store.state.deviceList.includes(this.$route.params.device)) {
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'NotFound'
        })
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.checkDevice()
  }
}
</script>
```